# C library warnings(pointer cast)

Tags: c, pointers, arraylist, warnings

I'm writing a C library and often I'm getting the warning  "warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]" or similar to it. For example:

```
int chal(chal_l* list, int pos)
{

  return list->data[pos];  \\warning occur here

}
```

This is about an arraylist. "pos" is the index. Data is in the arraylist struct as "void ** data". I'm not quite sure how to fix these warnings that are similar to this one and that I get 4-5 times in my code.

Comment: Your snippet should be [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org) -- we don't know what is stored in `list->data` => are those `int`s? if not, why do you define your function as one which returns an `int`? (hence the warning)

Comment: why can't I see it? try to be SSCCE as I mentioned before

Comment: I would have to paste all my code?

Comment: Nope, only the relevant parts: **SHORT** and **SELF-CONTAINED** => we don't need all the details, just the ones that are connected to your problem

Comment: `list->data` cannot be defined as `int*` or `int[]`, or you wouldn't get that warning.   Please provide the declaration of `chal_l`

Answer (score 0):

> Data is in the arraylist struct as "void ** data".

Which means the type of `list->data[pos]` is `void *`, not `int`, hence the warning.

If you're trying to return the value of `list->data[pos]`, then the return type of the function needs to be `void *`, not `int`.

If you're trying to return the value of an integer object that `list->data[pos]` *points to*, then you need to do something like the following:

```
return *( (int *) list->data[pos] );
```

that is, you convert `list->data[pos]` from a pointer to `void` to a pointer to `int` and dereference the result.

If `list->data[pos]` is pointing to something that *isn't* an integer, then I'm not sure what it is you're trying to do.